# Does anyone know if AutoDesk APIs are paid services?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are able to authenticate users through 3-legged oAuth2 with full scopes but the access token doesn't get us anywhere. We attempted to get a list of hubs for the Autodesk that our customer is running. But we are getting no accountId and messages about not having permission to access this API. The Autodesk userAccount being used for this is an admin account in Autodesk and it also grants access to the Autodesk Platform services which is the developer area.

Will appreciate guidance on this.

Thank you

Comment: I think they have like a 90 day trial for their API and then its a paid service, if that answers your question.  Their services have something to do with Flex Tokens per hour as their rate.

Answer (score -1):

Note that there's a couple of extra steps to take if you want your application to be able to access your users' data in products such as Autodesk Construction Cloud. Most importantly, the account admin must white-list your application (the Client ID) as a custom integration. See this section of our tutorials for more details: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/#provision-access-in-other-products.